# checkbox with 3 states which will act as 'Select all / Unselect all' in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, checkbox

I have a WPF window with a few checkboxes that are databinded to corresponding Boolean properties in my object. I have derived my object from INotifyPropertyChanged so changes in data are reflected in view, and changes in view are reflected in data.

Now I have to add another checkbox with 3 states which will act as 'Select all / Unselect all' and work as follows:

- If checked by user – will check all other checkboxes
- If unchecked by user – will uncheck all other checkboxes
- If all other checkboxes are checked – will be displayed as checked
- If all other checkboxes are unchecked – will be displayed as unchecked
- If some of the other checkboxes are checked – will be displayed as indeterminate

I'm new at WPF. How can I do it in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a MUCH better way to approach this problem but here's a quick solution I came up with that seems work work.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:AllNoneCheckboxConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chk1" Content="1"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chk2" Content="2"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chk3" Content="3"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="all" Content="all">
                <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="chk1" Path="IsChecked"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="chk2" Path="IsChecked"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="chk3" Path="IsChecked"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </CheckBox.IsChecked>
            </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the MultiValueConverter;

```
class AllNoneCheckboxConverter: IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool result = (bool)values[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                if (result != (bool)values[i])
                    return null;

            return result;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            object[] result = new object[targetTypes.Length];
            bool isChecked = (bool)value;

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                if (isChecked)
                    result[i] = true;
                else
                    result[i] = false;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Had to make a minor mistake in the 'ConvertBack' method because 'isChecked' is of type bool?, and also implement the 'click' event for the 'all' checkbox

Comment: I may be misinterpreting your comment but I didn't need to do either of those to make the solution work. Are you familiar with databinding and converters? You definitely don't need to implement a handler for the click event. I'm not sure why you need to use a nullable boolean for the convert back, the 'all' checkbox can only have IsChecked set to true or false when it's clicked.

Comment: I've looked at it again and saw that I've defined the 'all' checkbox as 'IsThreeState="True"', and you didn't. I think this was the reason I got an exception on the ConvertBack method, and that's why I made the change in that method. I've modified my code to be exactly as yours, and it works, though I still don't understand why I don't need to define the 'IsThreeState' property of the 'all' checkbox as 'True'.